# How do I load a form with a specific form display (form mode)?

Tags: 8, forms, entities

On a custom page I'm trying to load an user edit form with a specific form display.
I'm able to load the form however I can't figure out how to load the form with the specific display.

This is what I have now:

```
public function content($substep) {

    $user = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('user')
      ->load(1); // loading user 1 for test purpose

    $form_state = new FormState();

    $form = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getFormObject('user', 'default')
      ->setEntity($user);

    return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
}
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by 'specific display'? Forms don't have display modes, that's only for viewing entities.

Comment: It's technically called a "form mode" @Jaypan but D8 does have them

Comment: Interesting. Some more research has shown me more about this. I didn't even realize this existed in D8.

Answer (score 15):

In D8 you can add display modes for forms in UI. But these form modes can't be used right away like view modes.

If you want to use a form mode in code you have to set a form operation with the same name in the handlers section of the entity type. The form class you use for this handler is the same as in the default handler, because you want to control which fields are displayed in the form mode, not in a different form class.

For example to use a form mode `profile2`, which you have configured in UI, you have to add a form operation `profile2` to the user entity type definition in a [hook_entity_type_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_build/8.2.x):

*mymodule.module*

```
function mymodule_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['user']->setFormClass('profile2', 'Drupal\user\ProfileForm');
}
```

Then you can use the new form operation (form mode) in the code example from the question:

```
public function content($substep) {

  $user = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('user')
    ->load(1); // loading user 1 for test purpose

  $form = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getFormObject('user', 'profile2')
    ->setEntity($user);

  return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
}
```

Comment: Loading the `$form_state` isn't necessary.
Also, keep in mind that when creating a form mode for the user entity with machine name `user.profile2`, for example, only `profile2` is needed in code, as shown above.

Answer (score 4):

Found this answer really helpful,

```
function my_module_entity_form_display_alter(&$form_display, $context) {
  if($context['entity_type'] == 'user' && $context['bundle'] == 'user'){
    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    if(!in_array('administrator', $user->getRoles())){
      $storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('entity_form_display');
      $form_display = $storage->load('user.user.restricted');
    }
  }
}
```

Via [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-05-14/how-to-specifymodify-form-view-mode).  Also, [form_mode_manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_control) seems like a contrib way to fix this problem via the UI.

Comment: Thank you! I tried form_mode_manager module and https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_control, but neither worked. This snippet works great. It's frustrating that using form modes is not part of the core GUI. Why let us create something through the GUI and then give us no way to use it through the GUI?

Answer (score 4):

In Addition to @powpow12 answer, you could use the route name to edit the display mode on a form only for embed forms, like the entity browser "edit entity" option.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_form_display_alter().
 */
function mr_media_entity_form_display_alter(&$form_display, $context) {
  $route_service = \Drupal::service('current_route_match');
  $route_name = $route_service->getRouteName();

  if ($route_name == 'entity_browser.edit_form' && $context['entity_type'] == 'media' && $context['bundle'] == 'image) {
    $storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('entity_form_display');
    $form_display = $storage->load('media.image.edit_for_entity_browsers');
  }
}
```