# Programmatically render user edit form with form mode

Tags: 8, forms, display-suite

I can't figure out to render the user profile form with a custom display mode. I did search the forum and internet and it seems that this piece of code should work:

```
 function mymodule_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
      $entity_types['user']->setFormClass('my_custom_form_display_mode_id', 'Drupal\user\ProfileForm');
}
```

combined with

```
$user = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
->getStorage('user')
->load(1); 
$formObject = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getFormObject('user', 'my_custom_form_display_mode_id')
  ->setEntity($user);
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);
```

However, the form that gets loaded actually contains all fields and is not even using the default form mode. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The approach is correct, but you mix node and user.

Comment: Im sorry, i just copied the code from the other post on the forum, ill edit my post. However, with the new updated code it still not works.

Comment: now it's the same as https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230527/how-do-i-load-a-form-with-a-specific-form-display-form-mode, can't tell what went wrong in your case, did you some basic debugging, for example checking if the code is run?

Comment: Not sure what to debug though, i mean the code gets executed but it just doesn't use any display mode.