# Form in custom module using Controller: The HTML tag form isn't present in Twig

Tags: theming, forms, hooks

I'm trying to render limited user edit form on custom page using Drupal Controller.
In the routing.yml I defined _controller, I do not want to use _form.

I want to display on the form e.g. only timezone field, but not the rest. And I'm not able to achieve it. I can render this field, other fields like form_build_id, form_id, form_token
But form html tag is not rendered at all.
It works only if I display the whole form with `{{ form.form }}`.

This is the content of the files I am using.

#### my_module.info.yml

```yaml
name: 'My module'
type: module
description: 'my module'
core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9
```

#### my_module.routing.yml

```yaml
my_module.mymodule_controller_view::
  path: '/my-module'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MymoduleController::view'
    _title: 'My module'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

#### my_module.module

```php
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    $templates = array(
        'my_module_form' => [
            'render element' => 'form',
        ],
    );

    return $templates;
}
```

#### MymoduleController.php

```php
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

class MymoduleController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function view()
    {
        $data['header'] = [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<h1>HEADER</h1>',
        ];

        $user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
        $formObject = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getFormObject('user', 'default')
            ->setEntity($user);

        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);

        $data['form'] = [
            '#theme' => 'my_module_form',
            'form' => $form,
        ];

        $data['footer'] = [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<h3>footer</h3>',
        ];

        return $data;
    }
}
```

#### my-module-form.html.twig

```
<div>TWIG TEMPLATE</div>

{{ form.form.timezone }}
{{ form.form.form_build_id }}
{{ form.form.form_token }}
{{ form.form.form_id }}
{{ form.form.actions }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not working, you can't use a form template in a controller. You have to assign the template to `$form['#theme']` when building the form or in a form alter hook. Then it gets used by `formBuilder()->getForm()` automatically.

See for example [seven_form_node_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21seven%21seven.theme/function/seven_form_node_form_alter/9.0.x):

```
$form['#theme'] = ['node_edit_form'];
```

and the corresponding twig file for a two column layout:

*core/themes/seven/templates/node-edit-form.html.twig*

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a node edit form.
 *
 * Two column template for the node add/edit form.
 *
 * This template will be used when a node edit form specifies 'node_edit_form'
 * as its #theme callback.  Otherwise, by default, node add/edit forms will be
 * themed by form.html.twig.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - form: The node add/edit form.
 *
 * @see seven_form_node_form_alter()
 */
#}
<div class="layout-node-form clearfix">
  <div class="layout-region layout-region-node-main">
    {{ form|without('advanced', 'footer', 'actions') }}
  </div>
  <div class="layout-region layout-region-node-secondary">
    {{ form.advanced }}
  </div>
  <div class="layout-region layout-region-node-footer">
    <div class="layout-region-node-footer__content">
      {{ form.footer }}
      {{ form.actions }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Form modes**

A different approach would be to configure a form mode in UI containing only the field you want and then use it in your controller:

```
    $formObject = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getFormObject('user', 'custom_form_mode')
        ->setEntity($user);
```

See [How do I load a form with a specific form display (form mode)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230527/how-do-i-load-a-form-with-a-specific-form-display-form-mode)

Comment: Thank you @4k4 very much!! This code $form['#theme'] in hook_theme() (used in module, not theme) helped.
But with this user_edit form I have now another problem. I'm displaying only field timezone, but after saving it resets my roles. Other values (mail, custom fields) seems to be untouched. Any idea why?

Comment: Normally values not submitted by a form element should not be overwritten. But I've seen in the edited question that you render `{{ form.account.roles }}`

Comment: Maybe it was just my mistake, I do not have {{ form.account.roles }} in my twig. Standard user doesn't overwrite roles when submitting this form, but as admin user I will reset all my roles. Maybe this is bug in Drupal?
------------ Hm, I don't know what happened but my update is gone :-(

Comment: This is what was missing: `function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {     if ($form_id == 'user_form') {         $form['#theme'] = ['my_module_about_form'];     } }`