# User edit form on custom page is resetting roles when user belongs to the "Administrator role"

Tags: theming, forms, 9

I'm trying to display the user edit form on a custom page with limited fields. Submitting my form works well, but if I have the *Administrator* role, roles are reset. I don't understand why this is happening.

This is the routing file custom_user_profile.routing.yml.

```
my_module.default_controller_view:
  path: '/my_module'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\DefaultController::view'
    _title: 'Account'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
  options:
    no_cache: 'TRUE'
```

In the controller DefaultController.php I have

```php
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

class DefaultController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function view()
    {
        $user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());

        $html = '';
        $html .= '<p>Current email is ' . $user->mail->value . '</p>';

        $data['html'] = [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => $html,
        ];

        $user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
        $formObject = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getFormObject('user', 'default')
            ->setEntity($user);

        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);

        $data['form'] = [
            'form' => $form,
        ];

        return $data;

    }

}
```

In the my_module.module I have following code.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    $templates = array(
        'my_module_about_form' => [
            'render element' => 'form',
        ],
    );

    return $templates;
}

function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == 'user_form') {
        $form['#theme'] = ['my_module_about_form'];
    }
}
```

In the template file my-module-about-form.html.twig I have the following lines.

```
{{ form.timezone }}

{{ form.form_build_id }}
{{ form.form_token }}
{{ form.form_id }}
{{ form.actions.submit }}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You need to show more code. It's not sufficient to write _In the controller I use the following code_; the question should show all the method code, or it would not be clear in which way the code is related to the route definition given. The question should show more of the template file used. Also, since you already asked https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295479/form-in-custom-module-using-controller-the-html-tag-form-isnt-present-in-twig, you should show the code after fixing what already reported there.

Comment: Hi @kiamlaluno please check my edits. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The form values still persist in the form state, and as they're not printed, the will be submitted as empty and saved accordingly.

Do not hide form element by not outputting them in twig, render the full form there and use `[#access] = FALSE;` on the form elements you don't want to show. Do so in the controller, to only have that on your custom page. If you do that in hook_form_alter it will apply to the form always (so here also for the profile page aka /user/X/edit).

> You're mixing two concepts: Showing a form (where you have full
> control and can add stuff before and after with entries in the render
> array and use a form-mode for the form, so you can configure the
> fields via UI and not code) and altering a form (where you do not
> control where it is shown, and want to change it everywhere). I guess
> you want to show a form, so I would remove the theme stuff and
> concentrate only on the output form your controller.

Or even use a different approach .. and create a new form from scratch, populating with the user's value, and save them back to the user entity on submit (If you only need one "field" and even the password fields can be replicated in the custom form).
And replace the controller with a form callback in routing.yml.

Comment: Thank you @rémy. It is strange because only roles are cleared, other field values remains untouched. I would like to show specific fields only, not to hide them - in future new field can be created and it can easily happen to hide it. I like idea of populating, but I don' t know how to do it.

Comment: Start here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api

Load the user (best to inject it in the constructor, see: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form), create the fields you want and populate them (using #default_value) with the user entity values (all in the build_form method).